# How to find an .xlsx file in folder in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two folders and one .xlsx file in `project_dir`. I want to switch to this folder and read the information in the .xlsx file into matlab but I seem to be having problems.

My Code:

```
project_dir='D:\MPhil\Model_Building\Models\TGFB\Vilar2006\SBML_sh_ver\vilar2006_SBSH_test7\Python_project3_IQM_project\vilar2006_SBSH_test6_2';
cd(project_dir)
dir *.xlsx
```

This work because it doesn't give me a handle to the xlsx file for subsequent reading.

```
dir(project_dir)
```

Also doesn't work because you get back a struct that can't be read by the xlsread function.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct where `dir` returns a structure array.  Each element in this array is information about each file that matched your search query when using `dir`.  You obviously can't use this structure outright, so you'll have to access things within it to get what you need.  First, you need to assign the output of `dir` to something:

```
d = dir('*.xlsx');
```

After this, you'll get a structure array where each element has a `name` field.  This field is the name of each file that matched your query using `dir`.  Therefore, you'd have to access each `name` field for each file individually and use this to finally open up your files.

For example, if you wanted the first Excel file, you'd do:

```
fileName = d(1).name;
```

`fileName` would contain the string of the name of the first Excel file, then you can use that to read in the file:

```
out = xlsread(fileName);
```

Alternatively, if you have more than one Excel file and you want to process them individually, consider putting this inside a loop:

```
d = dir('*.xlsx'); %// Find all Excel files

%// For each file...
for idx = 1 : numel(d)
    fileName = d(idx).name; %// Get the file name

    out = xlsread(fileName); %// Read the Excel file

    %//..... rest of your code follows
end
```

---

If on the off-chance you are wanting to find Excel files that are not in the current working directory, you can do something like below.  Bear in mind that when using `dir`, it finds the files **with respect to the input directory you specified**.  This does not form absolute paths.  As such, to successfully open up files, you'll need to piece together the directory you specified plus the relevant filename local to that directory.  You can use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to help you do that:

```
directory = '/put/my/directory/here'; %// Place directory to search for Excel files here

%// Create absolute path to search for Excel files
searchString = fullfile(directory, '*.xlsx');

%// Find the file names
d = dir(searchString);

%// For each file...
for idx = 1 : numel(d)
    fileName = fullfile(directory, d(idx).name); %// Get the file name

    out = xlsread(fileName); %// Read the Excel file

    %//..... rest of your code follows
end
```

If you are finding files in the current working directory, then the `fullfile` stuff isn't required.... it's something to think about if you want to search for Excel files that aren't in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

How about one of these small scripts?

```
% % Import all excel files in a folder into multiple Matlab variables.
% % Your variables will be num1, num2, ...etc
d = dir('C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Excel_Files\*.xls*'); 
nfiles = length(d);
for k = 1:nfiles
   n=int2str(k);
   eval(['[num' n ', txt' n ', raw' n '] = xlsread(d(k).name,1);']);  
end


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  

source_dir = 'C:\Users\xuf\Desktop\Excel Saved PointScans'
dest_dir = 'C:\Users\xuf\Desktop\Test Folder'
source_files = dir(fullfile(source_dir, '*.xls'));

for i = 1:length(source_files)
    data = xlsread(fullfile(source_dir,source_files(i).name));
    xlswrite(fullfile(dest_dir,source_files(i).name));
end  


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  
% % Import multiple files into one single Matlab variable.

********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  

cd('C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Excel_Files')
d = dir('*.xls');
nfiles = length(d);
data = [];
for k = 1:nfiles
   num = xlsread(d(k).name);
end
```